# They ARE Klingons, and it's a long story... What's the story?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-tos, klingon

I just watched the episode of Star Trek DS9 *Trials and Tribble-ations* where the Defiant is taken back in time to the events of ‘The Trouble with Tribbles’ episode from Star Trek TOS. Those who remember the TOS Klingons know that they they don't look anything like Klingons as we now know them.

<sup>23rd Century Klingons:</sup>
[image]

When they're pointed out to Bashir and Odo as Klingons, they look on in disbelief, then all heads turn to Worf for an explanation:

Worf says that they *are* Klingons, but that it's a long story, and it isn't discussed with outsiders.

What's the story? Why do these 23rd century Klingons look like humans?

Comment: Strongly related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1056/769 and more generally https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/20579/769

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do the Klingons in Into Darkness have cranial ridges?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119563/why-do-the-klingons-in-into-darkness-have-cranial-ridges). A rare case where a *question* answers another question.

Comment: They actually provide the answer in the video, "Genetic engineering? Viral mutation?"

Comment: Star Trek's motto has always been "we hate continuity"

Answer (score 122, accepted):

### Viral Mutation

This apparent discrepancy was explained in *Star Trek Enterprise*. Long story short, Klingons experimented with genetic mutation to make themselves stronger, much like what was accomplished with Kahn and the Augments, but there were side effects that made the Klingons look "hoo-mahn". These side effects were spread by a resulting virus, and after a cure was developed the human traits ware still passed on genetically by some.

[*From Memory Alpha:*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Klingon_augment_virus)

> In 2154, Klingon scientists working under the direction of Antaak
>   recovered several Augment embryos from a hijacked Bird-of-Prey
>   destroyed in orbit of Qu'Vat colony during the Augment Crisis. Fearing
>   that Humans could overwhelm the Empire if they moved to staffing their
>   ships with Augments, a project was set up to attempt to create their
>   own Augments to counter the perceived threat.
>
> The effort failed dreadfully. The Augments created did develop
>   enhanced strength and intelligence, but they also began to show Human
>   characteristics, from the blatant to the subtle. These included
>   personality alterations and loss of the characteristic forehead
>   ridges. Ultimately, the subjects died agonizing deaths when the
>   incompatible DNA resulted in neural system breakdown. While working to
>   stabilize the augmentation process, the scientific team enhanced a
>   test subject who was, unknown to the team, also infected with Levodian
>   flu. The flu virus in some manner incorporated the Augment DNA,
>   turning a carefully controlled experiment into an epidemic. As the
>   unstable augmentation process always killed the subject, this epidemic
>   threatened the Klingon race with extinction.
>
> The virus spread very rapidly, infecting millions within months. One
>   of the first planets struck was N'Vak Colony. The Klingons attempted
>   to capture Doctor Arik Soong to help develop a cure, but their efforts
>   were thwarted by Soong's incarceration in a high security detention
>   facility. They then moved to kidnap Doctor Phlox, using Rigelian
>   intermediaries and the assistance of Section 31 agents. Phlox was
>   forced to work with Antaak to find a cure. However, the Klingon High
>   Council was unwilling to wait, and dispatched a fleet to annihilate
>   the infected planets, starting with N'Vak Colony. Afterward it set
>   course to Qu'Vat colony. (ENT: "Affliction")
>
> When it became
>   clear to the research team on Qu'vat colony that it would take weeks
>   to develop a cure, stabilizing the augment virus became the
>   researcher's primary concern. Their efforts proved successful; a
>   method was developed that stabilized the process in the early stages,
>   after the cranial ridges had dissolved and some minor neural
>   re-ordering had occurred (which caused personality changes), but
>   before the virus became contagious, enhanced augment abilities, and
>   caused a fatal neural pathway breakdown.
>
> Eventually, Admiral Krell convinced the High Council to call off their
>   sterilization program of destroying the infected planets. The cure was
>   distributed throughout the Empire. Because afflicted Klingons' DNA had
>   been altered by the virus, the Human appearance and genetic traits
>   were passed onto the descendants of the infected. Initially there were
>   millions of Klingons who had to live with the disfigurement. (ENT:
>   "Divergence")
>
> In 2154, Antaak and Laneth
>   feared that Klingons without ridges would become outcasts, lose their
>   positions and would no longer have a place in the Empire. (ENT:
>   "Divergence") However, by the 2260s, affected Klingons served as the
>   captains and crews of front-line starships in the Klingon Defense
>   Force. (Star Trek: The Original Series) Later on, some of them even
>   achieved the title of Dahar Master and earned their statues among the
>   Hall of Heroes on Qo'noS. (DS9: "Blood Oath", "The Sword of Kahless")
>
> By the 24th century, knowledge of Klingons with smooth foreheads had
>   been generally forgotten by the population of the United Federation of
>   Planets. Also, the reason for Klingons having smooth foreheads a
>   hundred years earlier was not widely known outside the Empire. When
>   asked by Miles O'Brien and Julian Bashir, Worf simply gave the answer
>   "we don't discuss it with outsiders", though Bashir immediately
>   suspected viral mutation to be the cause. (DS9: "Trials and
>   Tribble-ations")

Comment: Don't cut-and-paste from another site. *"Antaak Antaak before Antaak-ridgeless Antaak after"* If it's a quote, put it in a blockquote (and fix the quoted captions)

Comment: Not sure it's worth mentioning, but this is also part of the core story in one of *Star Trek Online*'s seasons, for those preferring a game over *Enterprise*. :)

Comment: Well curing it is, it doesn't retcon anything from that series it merely explains how they got back to "normal".

Comment: ehh, can this quote be summarized?

Comment: @DoritoStyle there was an Enterprise plot arc about genetic engineering and conspiracy that was supposed to simultaneously create drama for the Klingons and explain the appearance discrepancy between TOS and TNG. It was silly,  and it made about as much sense, and enriched the universe about as much, as much as attempts to explain "the ship that made the Kessel run in less than twelve parsecs."

Comment: Haha thanks Hobbs, but I was hoping for an edit to the question

Comment: (ignore excess "as much")

Comment: @Adeptus - why not cut and paste?  Most SE sites don't like a simple link because those can break.  Usually they want a link with the relevant portion of the answer pasted.  Additionally, if the paste answers the question isn't that the point of the site?

Comment: Except that this doesn't explain why Kahless was ridgeless in The Savage Curtain. He would have lived before the "experiments". Not that anybody is really craving to remember The Savage Curtain, but if people are gonna play the game of trying to make the canon consistent, they need to do the *entire* canon.

Answer (score 125):

**IN-Universe** - As Worf said, it's something not discussed with non-Klingons.

**OUT of Universe** - To summarize, it's a very meta in-joke.

In the original series, they had a limited budget, and makeup options were few.  So the Klingons got goatees and dusky skin, and belt buckles made of bubble wrap.

When they made Star Trek: The Motion Picture, Roddenberry had the budget to give the Klingons the more alien look he maintained he wanted to give them all along.

But the fans went to great lengths to try to come up with an in-universe explanation for the change.  Both the possible explanations given in that scene were examples of those fan theories.

So when this episode came along, when we finally got to see "new" and "Classic" Klingons, there was much hope that an official reason would be given. So for Worf to then basically say "it's a secret" was a perfect response to that desire.

There was much screaming and shaking of fists.

Comment: This is an OUT of universe explanation, not an IN universe one, which is presumably what the asker is more interested in.

Comment: @Plutor - While undoubtedly true, it's also highly relevant, and more interesting than standard Trek babble (at least to me).  OP can choose as they like, of course.

Comment: @Plutor - The asker should have specified that then.

Comment: @Plutor we shouldn't presume that unless OP specifies it.

Comment: @Plutor: Well, the in universe answer is: ***Unknown, it's a secret*** which actually is in the answer.

Comment: Answer edited to specify in and out of universe facets of answer. I'd address the mutation events referenced in the other answer, but I vaguely recall that the events of Enterprise don't tie with the events of TOS, and as such may not be the same answer as in TOS/DS9 et al? Someone want to to clarify that for me?

Comment: @Krumia the in-universe answer is very much known, since we saw it in two episodes of Enterprise.

Comment: It's cruel how there's this good (half-) answer and then then there's the other copy-paste-from-wikia half answer. A truly good (and complete) answer would include both the story as it was known at the time of *Trials and Tribble-ations* and the subsequent retrosplainin they did on Enterprise.

Comment: Relevant TV Tropes link: [Lampshade Hanging](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging). (Obligatory warning — _TV Tropes link!_)

Comment: @Plutor - as the events of the show Enterprise are explicitly in a timeline altered by various time travel events (e.g. the temporal cold war, and the arrival of the Borg somewhat earlier than can otherwise be accounted for), it cannot be known *for certain* that the reason shown in those episodes is the same reason pointedly not revealed by Worf in the DS9 episode.

Comment: @Jules I thought there was something that precluded Enterprise from definitively being in the same timeline as TOS. Thankee

Answer (score 26):

At the time "Trials and Tribble-ations" was shot, nobody involved with the production of *Trek* had figured out an in-universe way to explain changes in makeup and costume budgets between 1966 and 1979 (when the Klingon cranial ridges first appeared in TMP).  So *at that time*, there was no in-universe answer.  Giving Worf the "we don't discuss it with outsiders" line was a good way to acknowledge that yes, we know there's a discrepancy on screen, but the explanation isn't relevant to the story that's happening right now.  And it was a funny line, which was well-suited to the episode as a whole.